# Why can't I solve this by factoring (i.e. why must I use the quadratic formula)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a rather simple question, but why is this method of solving invalid

$$(1-x)(3-x)-8=0$$
$$(1-x)(3-x)=8$$

$1-x=8 \implies x=-7$
$3-x=8 \implies x=-5$

While on the other hand this method of solving is valid

$$(1-x)(3-x)=0$$

$1-x=0\implies x=1$
$3-x=0\implies
 x=3$

I assume it has something to do with the constant term, but why does that invalidate this technique of solving the problem? Obviously, for the former problem the quadratic formula can be used.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your tex is not readible you can rewrite the equation as $x^2-4x-5=0$ so that $x=-1$ and $x=5$ are its solutions

Comment: I've edited your question. In future, you should write in MathJax. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: Have you tries putting $x=-7$ or $x=-5$ into the original equation, which gives to me the false statements $8\times 10-8=0$ and $6\times 8-8=0$ - something has clearly gone wrong. For a solution you would need to pay attention to both factors at the same time.

Comment: Your approach can be useful when $x$ is required to be an integer.  Then if you have something like $(1-x)(3-x)=8$ you can say that both $1-x$ and $3-x$ must be factors of $8$ and extract useful information from that.  It doesn't work when $x$ can be any real.

Answer (score 9):

The second is valid because if the product of two number equal to zero then at least one of them must be zero. That is $ab = 0$ hence $a = 0$ or $b = 0$.

For the first one it is not the case, for example $2\times 4 = 8$ while none of them are $8$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem stems from the fact that from $(1−x)(3−x)=8$, you cannot deduce that 
$(1−x) = 8$ or $(3−x)=8$.

To see this, and if you really insist not using the quadratic formula, you could proceed as follows. Let $a = 1-x$. Since $3-x = 2 + (1-x)$, your equation becomes $a(a+2)=8$.
In this very special case, it is easy to find two numbers with difference $2$ and product $8$, namely $2$ and $4$. Is it the unique solution? No, $-2$ and $-4$ also work. This leads to either $a = 2$ (whence $x = -1$) or $a = -4$ (whence $x = 5$). Thus the two solutions of your equation are $-1$ and $5$.

Now, if you try to solve the equation $(1−x)(3−x)=0$ using the same approach, you get $a(a+2)=0$, which gives either $a = 0$ (whence $x = 1$) or $a = -2$ (whence $x = 3$). Thus the two solutions of this equation are $1$ and $3$.